# Handle an intent in Xamarin

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin

I am stuck at this problem quite a while now and i do not know how to proceed..

I am integrating Auth0 authentification into my Xamarin App:
[Link to Xamarin Auth0 tutorial i am working with](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/xamarin/01-login)

I have created an interface and implemented it in the .Android project. Then i used dependency services to call the login() method.

I then added the intent filter to the class where i implemented the login method to manage the callback.

The problem is that i am now stuck in my Android implementation and do not know how to get back into my shard project. Can i use the intent to redirect me there?

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Auth0.OidcClient;
using Ester.MobileApp.DependencySvcAuth;
using Ester.MobileApp.Droid.DependencySvcAuth;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Auth_Android))]

namespace Ester.MobileApp.Droid.DependencySvcAuth
{

    [Activity(Label = "Login Activity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]

    [IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "---",
        DataHost = "---",
        DataPathPrefix = "---")]
        


    class Auth_Android : Activity , IAuth
    {

        public async Task login()
        {
            
            var client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                Domain = "---",
                ClientId = "---"
            });


            var loginResult = await client.LoginAsync();

            
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are using Auth0 but not in the main activity but through a dependency service is there a reason for doing that?

Comment: Yes because i want to call the login() from a different site of my app and not on startup.Is there a way to call the login method which would be in the main activity from a point in my shared project? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Okay, Wait I will update an answer for you no worries! Just need to know that you only have one activity in your project am i right?

Comment: Yes i have only one activity in my project - the MainActivity, which calls the "LoadApplication(new App()"

Comment: Okay great will let you know what to do soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, Open your MainActivity.cs and add the following intent filters to it:

  ```
  [Activity(Label = "AndroidSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",
  LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
  [IntentFilter(
   new[] { Intent.ActionView },
   Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
   DataScheme = "YOUR_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME",
   DataHost = "YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN",
   DataPathPrefix = "/android/YOUR_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME/callback")]
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
  ```

  > Replace YOUR_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME in the code sample above with the actual Package Name for your application, such as com.mycompany.myapplication. Also ensure that all the text for the DataScheme, DataHost, and DataPathPrefix is in lower case. Also, set LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask for the Activity, otherwise the system will create a new instance of the activity every time the Callback URL gets called.
- Then write code to handle the intent. You can do this by overriding the OnNewIntent method. Inside the method you need to call the Send method on the ActivityMediator to complete the authentication cycle:

  ```
   protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
  {
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);

     Auth0.OidcClient.ActivityMediator.Instance.Send(intent.DataString);
  }
  ```
- Then add the `Auth0Client` field to your MainActivity class:

  ```
  public Auth0Client client;
  ```
- Then initialize that client something like this in your `MainActivity` OnCreate:

  ```
  client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
      {
          Domain = //**yourDomain**
          ClientId = //**clientID**
          Scope = //**Auth0Scope** //Optional
      });
  ```
- In your shared Project add the following interface as follows:

  ```
   public interface IAuthLogin
   {
       bool Auth0Login();               
   }
  ```

  The interface method `Auth0Login` return type can be changed to anything as per your need also you can add method arguments if needed.
- Then Add a class named Auth0Login.cs:

  ```
  [assembly: Dependency(typeof(AnalyticsManager))]
  namespace Ester.MobileApp.Droid.DependencySvcAuth
  public class Auth0Login: IAuthLogin
  {
     public async bool Auth0Login()
     {

     }           
  }
  ```
- Then add the [Plugin CurrentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) by James Montemagno
- Then in your Auth0Login Method :

  ```
  var currentActivity= CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity as MainActivity;
  var loginResult = await currentActivity.client.LoginAsync();
  if (loginResult.IsError)
      {
        return false;  // Login Failure 
      }
  else
      {
        return true; // Login Sucess
      }
  ```
- Then Call this method from your Shared Project like this :

  ```
   var authLoginManager= DependencyService.Get<IAuthLogin>();
   authLoginManager.Auth0Login();
  ```

I hope this works well for you

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive answer, however is it not possible no inherit from the Activity class because the MainActivity already inhertis from the "global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity"

Comment: Yeah I know that was a mistake from my side sorry its okay if you use `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` instead

Comment: I implemented as described (Just made a Task out of the function to return for async)  but unfortunately the browser does not open. We reach the breakpoint for the "var login result = await ..." line but we do not get further

Comment: I saw a mistake: I did not made the caller funtion async. Doing so throws an NullreferenceExeption. The same Exception i get when returning nothing from the Login function and undoing the Task implementation. It looks like "var loginResult = await currentActivity.client.LoginAsync();" is throwing a nullreferenceException

Comment: Are you using the current activity plugin and have you configured it properly if not check [this](https://montemagno.com/access-the-current-android-activity-from-anywhere/)? Also, I have not made the function as `Task<bool>` while using async kindly change that as well.

Comment: Yey it works now. Looks like i have not configured the plugin correctly. THANK YOU SO MUCH. One thing left: What i meant is that this line " public async bool Auth0Login()" does not work...either Task or void but not bool (:

Comment: No problem, Actually this `public async bool Auth0Login()` was a mistake from my side the reason I did this `public async Task<bool>Auth0Login()` later was so that you can get a boolean callback from the method in to your PCL with true or false so that you know whether the login was successful or not. I hope I make sense now!